# Eclipse shortcut keys: What package is this class?

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a hot key to display the package of a class when the cursor is on it?

Comment: What do you mean, "namespace"?

Comment: if I place the cursor on FileOutputFormat, I want to press a key and see: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat

Comment: You can add the windows "Declaration" or "Javadoc" to your IDE (Window -> show view). Both will do their respective tasks, including showing the package.

Comment: I am pretty sure the answer to your question is 'F2' (Its the focus hot-key). If you have a method highlighted and press it you'll see the window. That being said, it is linked to the Javadoc window. As a side note, Eclipse is open source and relatively easy to build. If you need a feature feel free to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I tested this just now. 'F2' is the hot-key to display the window. Again I'd recommend using the Javadoc view.

Answer (score 1):

Just move the mouse over the class and Eclipse will display the full package, as well as the Javadocs if available.